# Why does NOT the ubuntu 13.10 have the version.h?

Tags: kernel, make

```
/usr/src/linux-header-3.11.0.12
/usr/src/linux-header-3.11.0.12-generic
```

Neither has the `version.h` file in the `/include/linux/`.
Why?

That hinders the softwares installation.

but the ubuntu 11.10 has it .

Comment: Have you installed the headers package - sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) ?

Comment: I have tried , no need help ,

Comment: It is said that use make dep under the kernel source folder can generate the file , but make dep can't run .

Comment: Are you trying to build something ? Its best if you can provide the exact error message, if you are trying to install or compile some application/kernel module. etc. Note: thr is no path `/include/linux` under which you will find headers.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/include/linux/version.h` is in package `linux-libc-dev`

Comment: you mean I should install the software package of linux-libc-dev ?

Comment: Yes do `apt-get install linux-libc-dev`

Comment: unable to locate package linux-lib-dev

Comment: It is linux-libc-dev not linux-lib-dev

Comment: thanks , I tried ,and it it not helpful, it is still not exist .

Comment: It is said that use make dep under the kernel source folder can generate the file , but make dep can't run .

Comment: [Look at this linux-libc-dev file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/linux-libc-dev/filelist) - it includes `/usr/include/linux/version.h`. You do not need to manually install it.

Comment: yes , it stay in there , but why it not exsit in the /usr/src/linux-header-3.11.0.12-generic ? A software need it in there during its installation.

Comment: What software? Normal software should not be linking against headers in the kernel source.

Comment: Jungo WinDriver , the x86 version can be installed on ubuntu11.10 successfully because it has the version in the header generic folder,